# Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: Exception occurred while executing 'list':

Tags: android, react-native, expo, adb

I've recently upgraded my phone to android 13,now i'm trying to run a very simple react native project via expo go,but i getting these errors.I've updated expo go ,but it didn't work.

Opening exp://127.0.0.1:19000 on SM_A528B

Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: Exception occurred while executing 'list': java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 150 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser: 14872 android.app.ActivityManager.handle IncomingUser:4882 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellComman d.translateUserId:3499

at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser (UserController.java:2672)

at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser (ActivityManagerService.java:14872) at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser (ActivityManager.java:4882)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManager ShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3499)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages (PackageManagerShellCommand.java:965)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages (PackageManagerShellCommand.java:861)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runList(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:720)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:222)

at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)

at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:6922)

at android.os.Binder.shellCommand (Binder.java:1085)

at android.os.Binder.onTransact (Binder.java:903)

at android.content.pm.PackageManager$Stub.onTransact (IPackageManager.java:4989)

at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:6986)

at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1321) at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:1288)

Comment: I got the same error today using the same device. I am starting to think that maybe the problem is the Samsung device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

**You can bypass this issue by <s>uninstalling</s> disabling Secure Folder on your device (remember to backup your data). A known fix is unavailable at this time.**

This error may be caused by the fact that some devices support multiple user accounts and adb attempts installing the build on all accounts. However, one of the users (user 150) cannot be manipulated from adb due to restricted privileges from the device manufacturers. This happened to me recently after updating my Samsung S21+ to OneUI 5, I could no longer run expo dev-client builds.

Attempts to restrict packages from interacting with adb on that user account failed. I believe this is an inherent issue from Samsung related to OneUI 5.